# Why does the Django Atom1Feed use atom:updated instead of atom:published?

Tags: python, django, feed, atom-feed

I made an Atom feed in Django using a class that looks something like this:

```
class AtomFeed(Feed):

    feed_type = feedgenerator.Atom1Feed

    # ...

    def item_pubdate(self, post):
        return datetime.datetime(post.date.year, post.date.month, post.date.day)
```

The resulting XML for an item:

```
<entry>
  <title>..</title>
  <link href="..." rel="alternate"></link>
  <updated>2010-10-18T00:00:00+02:00</updated>
  <author><name>...</name></author>
  <id>...</id>
  <summary type="html">...</summary>
</entry>
```

The thing to note here is that the date goes in the `atom:updated` element, not the `atom:published` element.

The [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287#page-23) clearly suggests to me that this is not the intended usage:

> The "atom:updated" element is a Date construct indicating the most recent instant in time when an entry or feed was modified in a way the publisher considers significant.  Therefore, not all modifications necessarily result in a changed atom:updated value.

Whereas:

> The "atom:published" element is a Date construct indicating an instant in time associated with an event early in the life cycle of the entry.

This is more than just a theoretical problem. Google Reader, for example, does not seem to use the `updated` element, and uses the date that it first saw the item appear. As a result, it does not order the items properly upon first import of the feed.

The code in Django responsible for this:

[`django/utils/feedgenerator.py:331`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/utils/feedgenerator.py#L331)

```
if item['pubdate'] is not None:
    handler.addQuickElement(u"updated", rfc3339_date(item['pubdate']).decode('utf-8'))
```

There appears to be no mention of the `published` element.

Is this a bug in Django? Am I misunderstanding the Atom RFC? Am I missing something else?

Comment: I would say this is a definite bug in django.  When I say "when I published it", I don't want my translator saying "last time I changed it".  I see you've already [reported it](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14656), so I guess time will tell.

Comment: It doesn't seem like a "missing" feature. in Django 1.2 and 1.3 you can add attributes to the feed. If I remember well in 1.3 it is just necessary to add trough the method item_extra_kwargs of the Feed class. "return {'published': self.get_object().created }", this would work also to create podcast feeds and others kind of feeds with special items or attributes

Comment: That's good news, but it doesn't address the fact that the `atom:updated` element is abused, and that the important `atom:published` element isn't used out-of-the-box at all.

Answer (score 1):

You are not missing anything. The Atom RFC is correct, and this is a known bug in Django; see [this Django bug](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14656).

It looks like a relatively simple fix, so feel free to get in there and patch it! ^_^

Comment: Hmm... now that I have read the comments to your question, what's the betting that you are the one that filed the bug? ~_~

Comment: Yep, that was me ;) It has changed status to "accepted" though, so it has at least some degree of validity.

Comment: Well, this is what first Stack Overflow answers are for - learning to read the entire question first! =)